# Hibernate: how to insert foreign key id to a table

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to save `List<AuditScope> auditScopes` from `Audit` entity using Hibernate. `Audit` entity has One-to-Many relationship with `AuditScope` entity, `Audit` can have many `AuditScope`. I am using `saveAll()` method to batch insert `auditScopes` instead of saving one by one through a loop. Unforunately, I have to loop `auditScopes` just to set each `AuditScope`'s `auditId`(FK) manually instead of automatically. What I want is to batch insert them without looping and manually setting `auditId`. I am sorry my code is not good. Thank you very much.

Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="audit")
public class Audit {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="audit_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="audit_gen")
@Getter @Setter private int auditId;
@Getter @Setter private String auditName;
@Transient @Getter @Setter private List<AuditScope> auditScopes;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="auditScope")
public class AuditScope {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="auditScope_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="auditScope_gen")
@Getter @Setter private int auditScopeId;
@Getter @Setter private int auditId; //FK
@Getter @Setter private String scope;
}
```

Here's my `insertAudit()` method

```
public void insertAudit(Audit audit){
    //Save Audit first to get auditId
    Audit theAudit = auditRepository.save(audit);

    //Loop audit.getAuditScopes() to manually set auditId
    for(AuditScope scope : audit.getAuditScopes()){
        scope.setAuditId(theAudit.getAuditId());
    }

    //Save all AuditScope with set auditId
    auditScopeRepository.saveAll(audit.getAuditScopes());

    /*
       Expected result
       auditRepository.save(audit);
       auditScopeRepository.saveAll(audit.getAuditScopes());
    */

}
```

Comment: You can try to map auditId in AuditScope entity back to auditId from Audit entity. Example - @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "AUDIT_ID") on AuditScope.auditId

Comment: @DrKelso - Do advise if it worked for you. We could add it as an answer for easier reference for others facing similar problem.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response. An error occurred. `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne AuditScope.auditId references an unknown entity: int`. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Do share the changes in entity for better understanding.

Comment: And athe full stack trace of error

Comment: do also change the datatype from primitive int to Integer